# Site design testing

Tags: cross-browser

What websites and/or tools do people use when they make a website design and want to make sure it will look and function the same on say an ipad and all mobile devices as well as all desktop (pc and Ios) browsers.

So say I make a website design. Of course I can test what it looks like in chrome, IE and Firefox on my desktop but how can I test to make sure it looks the same in say an ipad or a nexus tablet without buying one. Which VM provides specialize in doing what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You can write some Selenium tests and run them under different browsers on different platforms. Passing tests will ensure your site is functioning property.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about media queries and measure metrics ( dpi, vw and so on... ) it is pretty easy when you understand this. Easiest way is with resolutions...

Answer (score 0):

You can open developer panel `(Chrome f12) -> Toggle device toolbar -> Responsive`

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piuOX.jpg)